# Joomla website and contact form emailing

Tags: email, joomla, joomla3.5, breezingforms, distribution-list

We are using Joomla Version 3 5 1/en. we have not updated to the latest version yet as we require a process of testing before doing so.

We use contact forms on our company website, via BreezingForms 1.8.3 Stable (build 831). These forms log any contact forms submitted and email them to a list of recipients who then deal with them. This has worked fine for a number of months and absolutely zero changes have been made to the configuration of joomla or breezing forms.

For out german contact form the email recipients are a customer service distribution list with an @DOMAIN.DE extension and an admin distribution list with an @DOMAIN.COM extension.

when the form is submitted, it is emailed to the .COM distribution list fine and all members receive it.

the .DE distribution list never receives the emails at all. this is confirmed by running a message trace via exchange.

Both DL's allow mail from internal and external senders, the spam was clear and message traces back up my findings.

However, when i created a new distribution list (ie, customerservice2@DOMAIN.COM) and made the .DE distribution list a member of it, the forms sent to the new DL and all recipients with no issues whatsoever, including the members of the .DE DL within it..

So, why are these contact forms not sending to .DE addresses?